# How to get the HTML source code after executing header(location:URL)

Tags: php, redirect, curl

My web hosting provider does not permit to use curl FOLLOWLOCATION option so I'm trying to
do it manually by using the header function.

My problem is that I need to keep my PHP script running and to be able to get the redirected URL data for parsing.

How do I do that?

Comment: I wish all these site parsing questions, except rss reading, were banned from SO.

Answer (score 1):

Technically the PHP script continues running after the header () function is called.  How you get URL data is another question.  Can you not use get_file_contents () or readfile () on the URL?

Answer (score 0):

You read the RAW data the request returns, you check for the redirect header(s), fetch the related URL(s) and do a new get with that URL (dry, rinse, repeat). As simple as that...

Alternatively you could stop being so lazy, check the [curl_setopt](http://www.php.net/curl_setopt) documentation in the PHP reference manual and find solutions - by reading the comments at the bottom of the page - on how to solve this problem of course.

Comment: I did read the curl_setopt doc.
Things would be more easy if I could use the FOLLOWLOCATION option.
I'll try to redirect manually using header and than read and parse the HTML content of redirected URL.

Comment: Then you didn't read the comments (I specifically told you to read these, didn't I?), because there are functions there that you can copy/paste that will do exactly what you want.

Comment: BTW They're here : http://www.php.net/curl_setopt#95943 or http://www.php.net/curl_setopt#95027 (just found out that they include anchors in the comments). The first one will also cover HTML META redirects, so probably is better then the second one.